# list<> sum overload

Tags: c#, list, generics, overloading

I have a class here that I want to sum(for every Traid T in list)(T.Price*T.Buy). (Buy is +1 if it is a Buy, -1 one if a sell).  So for instance if I have {Buy=-1,Price=10} and {Buy=1, price is =4} I would get -6.  I want an eloquent way to do this, I am assuming I should do some kind of overloading?  I'm new to programming and haven't done this before.  Thanks in advance.

-Rik

```
    private class Traid
        {
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public int Index { get; set; }
            public int Buy { get; set; }
            public int Price {get;set;}
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx):

```
int total = list.Sum(t => t.Price*t.Buy);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Linqs Sum() Method on IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Trade> trades = GetTrades();
var sum = trades.Sum(trade => trade.Buy * trade.Price);
```